# May the proof of Calculus on Manifolds Theorem 3-11 (on compact sets) be simplified as follows?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, alternative-proof

**Theorem:** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact, and let $O$ be an open cover of $A$. Then there is a partition of unity subordinate to $O$.

Below I give Spivak's proof and my slight simplification. **Is my proof (the simplified version of Spivak's) correct?**

---

*Spivak's proof:*

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

---

*My Proof:*

Let $U_1,\ldots, U_n$ be a finite subcover of $A$ in $O$. By **Lemma 1** there are compact sets $D_i$ such that
$$A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nD_i^{\circ} 
\ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ 
D_i\subseteq U_i.$$
Let $U:=U_1\cup \ldots \cup U_n$. By **Lemma 2** there are functions $\psi_i:U\to[0,1]$ so that

1. $\psi_i$ is $C^{\infty}$.
2. $\psi_i$ is $1$ on $D_i$.
3. $\psi_i$ is $0$ outside of some closed set contained in $U_i$.
   Define
   $$\phi_i : U\to [0,1] : x\mapsto \frac{\psi_i(x)}{\psi_1(x) + \ldots + \psi_n(x)}.$$
   The partition of unity $\Phi:=\{\phi_1,\ldots ,\phi_n\}$ is subordinate to $O$.

**Lemma 1 (akin to Spivak's Problem 1-22):**

1. Let $U$ be open and $K\subseteq U$ compact. Then there is a compact set $D$ such that
   $$K\subseteq D^{\circ}
    \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ 
   D\subseteq U.$$
2. Let $\{U_1, \ldots , U_n\}$ be an open cover of the compact set $K$. Then there are compact sets $D_i$ such that
   $$K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nD_i^{\circ}
   \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ 
   D_i\subseteq U_i.$$

**Lemma 2 (akin to Spivak's Problem 2-26):** Let $U$ be open and $D\subseteq U$ be compact. Then there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

1. $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.
2. $f$ is $1$ on $D$.
3. $f$ is $0$ outside of some closed set contained in $U$.

---

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the notation of $D$ vs $L$ in your proof. Is there a typo?

Comment: @NickAlger Considering the $D$s are used in the proof, and the $L$s in the lemma, there is no type per se. That being said, I'll edit the post so as to mantain the notation consistent.

Comment: A slight issue is that your $\psi_1(x)+\cdots+\psi_n(x)$ is only positive on $D$, not necessarily on $U$, but maybe that doesn't matter in application